# i want to install nodejs in ubuntu, I installed nodejs and checked its version, it works correctly but npm is not getting installed properly

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

i have installed nodejs using the command :

```
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

after that i have checked its version and it shows : 
       v7.10.1
but when i checked the npm version using npm -v, it shows error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:6
let url
^^^
        SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
           at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
           at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
           at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
           at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
           at require (module.js:378:17)
           at Object.<anonymous> 
       (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry- 
       client/lib/access.js:5:11)
           at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
           at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

for installing npm i have used command : sudo apt-get install npm, the it shows like this

```
sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

update `apt-get update`
get install script and pass it to execute:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash
```

and install node `apt-get install nodejs`
confirm that it was successful `node -v` **npm installs automatically** `npm -v`

**Note** - don't use `apt-get install -y nodejs` instead use `apt-get install nodejs` which will install specified node version and npm automatically.

I hope this will resolve your problem. I have done the above steps and updated successfully without any issues. If you have any issues or doubts let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to install a package what depends of other packages with apt-get, apt-get only tries to install the most important package, apt-get do not install the dependencies. So, there is another package manager like apt-get, called aptitude, what installs package and the dependencies. So you may do something like this:

```
sudo aptitude install npm
```